# How to create edges in bulk in OrientDB (using links)?

Tags: graph-theory, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm looking to create multiple edges between two classes in bulk using OrientDB. I've seen examples here...

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Create-Edge.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/master/SQL.html

...but they only speak to creating edges using RIDs and that is not practical given the number of edges I'm looking to create.

I have created a link like this:

```
CREATE LINK lnk TYPE LINKSET FROM myClass.secondaryId TO Secondary.id INVERSE
```

... but how do I use it to create the edges? Note that I'm basically using a foreign key in myClass to "join" to my 2nd class. Presumably, after that edges are created, I can delete myClass.secondaryID??? Is there a better approach I should take?

The best my googling has uncovered makes references to the Java API but that isn't an option for me in the short term because I don't know Java.

Comment: If you don't want to use java you can try to implement it with javascript function.

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko Thanks for the suggestion. I'll certainly look into this. Are there alternative approaches?